# PHP mysql, update record fails but no error

Tags: php, mysql

PHP mysql, update record fail but no error.

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET password='$new_password' WHERE email='$email' AND id='$uId'";

//if ($mysqli->query($sql)) also result in True
if ($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {  
    $_SESSION['test6'] = $mysqli->error;  
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Your  password have been updated!";  
    header("location:gain.php");  
    }  
else {  
    $_SESSION['test7'] = "Error updating record: " . $mysqli->error;  
  }
```

I know why it don’t update, incorrect values in the `WHERE` clause. If the values are correct it updates just fine.
But no errors to be seen anywhere when it fails, with or without a successful update the `$mysqli->query($sql)` are `true`.

How to catch the error?
I'm new to this, and I should probably look into PDO or what it's called, but shouldn't mysqli give an error of some sort? This is on a XAMPP localhost.

Comment: if the values simply don't match anything in the tables, then it's not an error, it's just a query which didn't match any rows. Sometimes that can be a perfectly acceptable situation, so SQL doesn't consider it a failure. You can check the number of affected rows using http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php to know if it updated anything or not.

Comment: btw I hope you are escaping those variables before you concatenate them into your SQL otherwise you're a wide open book for SQL injection attacks. You should consider changing your code to properly parameterise your inputs. http://bobby-tables.com/ gives an explanation of the risk you may be running, plus examples of how to write your queries safely using php and mysqli. I hope you're hashing your passwords as well, and not storing them in plain text.

Comment: Also `header("location:gain.php");` should be followed immediately by `die();` otherwise your page could leak data it wasn't intended to.

Comment: Thanks a lot, 
For sure it makes sense that no record updated aren’t an error, :-)
If you think about it. 

Well not super safe stuff, so far only minimum security.
In all it now looks like in my answer to my query, didn’t bother to change language, did mix it.

Comment: aDyson, thanks! Will add the die(), later.

Comment: @LarsEriks consider accepting Matt's answer by ticking the checkmark next to the answer. It's done a voluntary basis, yet it's better to do that since it informs everyone and the system that a solution was solved and that the question was solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't get an error, because there was no error, your search criteria just did not match any results. If you want to get the number of rows affected by the query, do just that, use [`affected_rows()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.affected-rows.html).

```
$updated = $mysqli->affected_rows();

if ( $updated == 0 ) {
    echo "None were updated!";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it  make sense, if you think, something I shall start to do, someday ...:-)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php    
/* from userpage.php, user change password. */
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/script/_db.php';
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Stockholm");
setlocale(LC_ALL,'sv_SE.utf8');

$curEmail = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['curEmail']);
$uId = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['uId']);

$myQ = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE users.email = '$curEmail'";
$result = $mysqli->query($myQ);
$user = $result->fetch_assoc();

if(password_verify($_POST['password1'], $user['password'])) {
    if ( $_POST['password2'] == $_POST['password3'] ) {
        $new_password = password_hash($_POST['password2'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

        $sql = "UPDATE users SET password='$new_password' WHERE email='$curEmail' && id='$uId'";

        $resupdat = $mysqli->query($sql);
        $afRows = $mysqli->affected_rows;
        if ($resupdat === TRUE && $afRows > 0) {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Ditt lösenord har uppdaterats!";
            header("location:gain.php");
            }
        else {
            if($afRows == 0){ 
                $msg = $afRows."/ Password was not updated!";}

            $_SESSION['message'] = "Error updating record: " . $mysqli->error. "<br>".$msg;
            header("location:failure.php");
            }
        }
    else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "De lösenord du angett matchar inte, försök igen!";
        header("location:failure.php");
        }
    }   
else {
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Fel lösensord, försök igen!";
    header("location:failure.php");
    }
?>
```